# Calculating an average over groups in django

Tags: django

I would like to know in Django how to get the average number of grouped elements in my table per element (without using .extra(...) if possible).

Concretely I have a table (DwarvesEatingCakes) consisting of Dwarves and Cakes. Each pair (dwarf, cake) is unique. I want to get the average number of cakes eaten by each dwarf.

The following code does not seem to work:

```
avg_cakeeaten_dict = DwarvesEatingCakes.values('dwarf').annotate(num_cake=Count('cake')).aggregate(avg_cake_eaten=Avg('num_cake'))
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem is that you need to annotate something.  So while you can get the count of cakes eaten by each dwarf, there is nothing to aggregate the average on.   Why not add up all dwarves eating cakes number and divide by the number of entries in the table?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a ".objects" after DwarvesEatingCakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I ended up using is the following (based on Rob's answer):

```
num_entries = DwarvesEatingCakes.objects.count() # get the number of entries
num_dwarves = DwarvesEatingCakes.objects.aggregate(num_dwarf=Count('dwarf', distinct=True))
return num_entries / float(num_dwarves['num_dwarf'])
```

Of course you also make your checks against divide by 0. There might be a standard way of doing this though since it is a relatively common place query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am understanding you correctly, but I think you are wanting to compute this single number (using PostgreSQL syntax):

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT cake_id) AS REAL) / COUNT(DISTINCT dwarf_id) FROM dwarves_eating_cakes
```

It's possible there is some way to do that in a single QuerySet if you join the table with itself (commence handwaving), but that strikes me as both inefficient and awkward. Personally, I'm inclined to issue the query directly:

```
def cake_average() :
  from django.db import connection
  c = connection.cursor()
  c.execute("SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT cake_id) AS REAL) / COUNT(DISTINCT dwarf_id) FROM dwarves_eating_cakes")
  return c.fetchall()[0][0]
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can expand this function to compute additional statistics in the very same query.

Comment: I am not familiar with PostgreSQL syntax, but selecting distinct cakes and distinct dwarves and then dividing would not give me the right answer since two different dwarves can eat the same cake. Rob has the right answer. Thanks.